# vim - sending compile to split tab in Iterm2

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, iterm2

I was wondering whether it is possible to compile code from vim in one window to another split window on Iterm2 without losing focus on vim?

I understand that this is possible in Vim and tmux, but I would like to stick with Iterm2 if possible..

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) by tpope contains support for `iterm`. Maybe the approach (by using `tell`) can be used to implement support for `iterm2` as well. Check out the [iterm](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch/blob/master/autoload/dispatch/iterm.vim) dispatcher.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I ended up using tmux inside Iterm2 after research..